# background repeat image not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout with a repeated background image. I searched and fount [this tutorial](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-tile-background-image-in-android.html)
but seems not working for me!
the following shows activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the backrepeat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:dither="true"
android:src="@drawable/bg"
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

also put backrepeat.xml in drawable folder.
Should I add or remove some codes?

thanks

Comment: No sure I get your question correctly, so you want your background to be animated. If so, try [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

Comment: How big is your `drawable/bg` image?

Comment: size of bg image is 3px in 3px.does it matter?

Comment: actually not animated background Wenhui. it is just a logo that should repeat to full whole of screen.

Comment: I think you should increase the size of your image. could you make it 10px x 10px and try, Because for me it worked..

Comment: Thanks Hardik4560. It works. So the size of bg image is important. right? thank all guys

Comment: file type is png. but I've tried with gif and jpg. Now it's working with png 10px in 10px.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I've got in my app. It includes a hack to prevent ListViews from going black while scrolling.

drawable/app_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/actual_pattern_image"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="app_theme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/TransparentListView</item>
        <item name="android:expandableListViewStyle">@style/TransparentExpandableListView</item>
    </style>

 <style name="TransparentListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
  <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
 </style>

 <style name="TransparentExpandableListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ExpandableListView">
  <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
 </style>

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:theme="@style/app_theme">
```